# RESTful API - handling updates that depend on other updates

Tags: javascript, api, rest, frontend

I'm trying to design a RESTful API to serve data to a front-end JS app, and in future a native mobile app once I get round to writing it.

I'm fairly new to front-end dev, so API designs are also fairly new to me. I'm writing a table tennis league app to start my learning, and one of the endpoints doesn't seem to quite fit with any example I've read of recommended API structures.

I have two entities, leagues and players. A league has a collection of players, and when a result is entered the players switch "position" in the league if the winner was below the loser before the match was entered.

A standard REST API might have endpoints as follows to update the details of a specific player within the league:

(POST/PATCH) - /api/v1/leagues/{league-id}/players/{player-id}

e.g. /api/v1/leagues/1/players/12

This is fine, but in my case, when a result is entered into the web app, 2 different players need their "position" value updating via the API. Ideally, I would have this set as a unique field in the database, so only 1 player can be at each position within the league at any given time. However, if that were the case, using an API endpoint as above, my front-end app would need to calculate the new positions of the players based on the entered result, update player 1, and then if successful update player 2 (rolling back on failure). Following this structure, the position field cannot be made unique, as following the update of player 1, they both have the same position value until player 2 is updated.

The only other solution that I can think of is to have some other appropriately named endpoint that takes a "result" object, does the logic of working out the players new position on the server side, updates accordingly, and returns some data for the UI to re-bind and update to.

So my question is this: which of the 2 methods outlined above would you choose, and why?

If you choose the latter, what data would you return from the API call for the UI to bind to? A full league of player data? Or just the two players that have been updated?

Thanks

Comment: `Player ID` is the item in the URL not their current position or rank in the league. Your URL should always point to the same resource.

Comment: Yes sorry that wasn't clear, the URL above is updating player with ID of 12, and you'd pass a JSON object to that URL with the data to update the players position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I see two problems

1. you haven't defined enough resources
2. you are confusing http with your domain model

Try something like this

```
PUT /api/v1/matches/{match-id}

{ winner : { id }, loser : { id }, ... }
```

Put to the API a message describing the outcome of the game (POST is acceptable, PUT is better for idempotency).

As a *side effect* of this message's arrival, incorporate the results into your domain model.  It's your domain model that should include the rules that describe how the rankings of players change when a game is finished.

When somebody wants to see the rankings of the players...

```
 GET /api/v1/leagues/{league-id}/standings
```

you send them to a resource that returns a representation of the current rankings in your model.

The spelling of the uri doesn't particularly matter; I prefer "standings" because I believe that's a real thing in your domain.  But if you wanted to reflect the data structure of your resources without additional context, you might use a spelling like

```
GET /api/v1/leagues/{league-id}/players?orderBy=position
```

The data representation in the body of the request sent to you by the client isn't a serialization of an entity in your domain model, it's a serialization of a message addressed to your domain model.

Comment: Makes a lot of sense! In essence that's what I'm doing, sending a result to the server which performs the logic needed to update the league tables. It just didn't seem to fit with my api resources and your answer sums up perfectly why that was. In trying to keep it simple I was actually making it more complicated. What would you return from the request to send a new match to the api? Or would you leave the client to send a further request to update if it wants to?

Comment: Depends on the method you are using.  With PUT, I would hew as closely as possible to the HTTP spec: you return a representation of the resource that was just PUT.

Comment: With POST, you aren't so tightly constrained, so you could redirect to some other resource without offending the purists.

Answer (score 0):

The choice of where to calculate the positions within the league is really subjective - I would suggest doing it at the server, since it involves searching the database again (other players' scores).

Since you have multiple players and you may update 2 players at a time, it would be better to send the players' scores in the request body with their positions, and return the calculated full league information in the response for each request, because that would simplify your client code and ensure that you get the latest data.

This suggestion is based on the assumption that you do not have large number of players in a league (may be > 100). In that case, I would suggest approach 1 is better.

So your API URL can be..

> (POST) /api/v1/leagues/{league-id}

And your request body, can be

> "players":[
>       {"player-id":"101", "newScore":"10"}, 
>       {"player-id":"103","newScore":"20"}
>   ]

Your response can be the full list of players in the resulting league.

> "players":[
>       {"player-id":"101", "position":"1"}, 
>       {"player-id":"102", "position":"2"}, 
>       {"player-id":"103","position":"3"}
>       {"player-id":"104","position":"4"}
>       {"player-id":"105","position":"5"}
>   ]

Comment: Thanks, that is currently what I'm doing as there are only around 10 players per league. The only complication is when two players switch leagues. This occurs when the winner is in a promotion zone of a lower league and the loser is in a relegation zone. In this case I have to send two league worth of data back.

Comment: It still makes sense to send the updated leagues back and change your UI model. That way you can encapsulate the transaction and make your UI code simpler.